# how can i have the discounted price for each row?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, price, discount

The single price of our products will be reduced, if our customers buy a certain amount of our product.

In the cart, for each row, magento will calculate with the base price and at the end, magento will subtract the discount, but that's not what we want. We want the reduced price instead of the base price for each row in the cart, like on the screenshot below.

i hope you can help me, i'm looking for an answer for some hours now, and doesn't find any solution...

Comment: Use catalog rules instead of cart rules.

Comment: How do I do that? There isn't any condition that's depending on the amount in the cart.

Comment: You are right. Stupid idea. But why don't you use tier prices? I'm not sure whether the original price is shown then, though, but adding the original is easy then :-)

Comment: I use tier prices, because of that there is the discount at the end.. Our Customr thinks, that his customers maybe can't see the discount (don't ask me, how you can't see the discount at the end. haha), that is why i want to display the reducted priced in each row.

Answer (score 1):

Use tier prices instead of cart rules, they will not be displayed as discount.